# How to get active music player -- android

Tags: android

thanks for previous replies,

Is it possible to get package name of active and runningin service(background) music player. I can able to get the music actions(metachage or playstateChange) but when i use intent.getPackagename, im getting null. can anyone guide me on how to get the package name of music player.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Supplying the file URL and open it in browser does not make sense, because this URLs expire after a wile.

No, insofar as there is nothing magic in Android that denotes a "music player" from anything else.